# QGIS Profile Tool shows no profile

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, terrain, profile

I have installed and followed the process to produce an elevation profile from the Route Profile plug-in in QGIS, but for some reason I am getting no profile to appear.

The grids are from OS Terrain50 and the route is a polyline shapefile. The tool version is 3.7.0 and I am using QGIS Lyon 2.12.0 on a Mac (El Capitan).

[image: Profile Tool Screenshot]

I have attached a screenshot of what is appearing.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does the profile appear when you save it as PDF or PNG?

Comment: The min max of the graph is 0 and 0. Try setting the max to a non null value

Comment: No profile appears when I export it.

Comment: The min max boxes won't let me type anything in them.

Comment: are you sure that the layer is selected before you run the profile tool?

Comment: I'm running the same mac and QGIS version and I can confirm the tool does work (for me anyway).  Does it work using a temporary polyline rather than the selected one?  Does it work if you mosaic your raster tiles together?

Comment: I have first selected the path, then selected one of the grid layers in the layers palette, which you need to do before the plugin will run. I run the plugin and then then add the other grids, but still nothing.

Comment: I have tried using just one of the grids on its own, so I don't know if creating a mosaic will make any difference. Also, I did create a new vector layer and draw a path, with the same result - I assume that this counts as a temporary polyline?

Comment: I think it might be an issue of how you're selecting the path.  You should be selecting the path.  Try these steps: (1) select a raster layer in the table of contents and launch the profile tool (2) add the other raster layers (3) Select your profile layer in the table of contents (4) From the "selection" dropdown select "selected polyline -> this should switch your cursor to a hand with a pointing finger (5) select the polyline you want to use on the map display.  The profile should appear.

Comment: Hi Ed. Thanks for your reply. I have followed your steps, but the only part I am not sure about, is when you say (3) select your profile layer. Is that the path layer? If it is, I have tried that and I am not getting the pointing finger after selecting "selected polyline" in the drop down menu?

Comment: Hi Sean - yes I meant the path layer. In that case I can't suggest anything further I'm afraid.  A last step might be to reinstall the profile tool plugin (unless you've tried that already)?

Answer (score 3):

Here you have the screenshot with the sequence to get the profile of a line:

1. Click on your dem file.
2. Click on "Add layer" button.
3. Click on the points between you want to see the profile (double click to finish the line).

In case you already have a line drawn (shape with a route or something like that) just change "*Temporary polyline*" to "*Selected polyline*" and click on the line in the map.

[image]

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

At 3.8.3, here's what works for me:

I have a raster DEM and a vector point shapefile (the point shapefile does not have elevation values in its attribute table).  I want to create an elevation profile that follows the point shapefile, utilizing the underlying DEM elevation values:

1. Start the Profile tool.
2. Click the DEM in the QGIS Table of Contents.
3. In the Profile Tool, click the *Add Layer* button.  The highlighted DEM automatically appears in the tool.
4. Click the vector point shapefile in the QGIS TOC.
5. In the Profile Tool > Options pane, click the drop-down and select *Selected Layer*.
6. Voila!  The profile is displayed in the Tool's graph, as shown here:

[image]

Note: Resorting the shapefile points in a different order had no effect on the profile graph display.  From this, it appears that the Profile Tool displays the elevation graph in the order that the points were originally digitized.

Comment: If you can't view the profile, it may be due to your vector layer is a multi-line. Try switching to "selected polyline" or merge the lines into a singular line.

Answer (score 0):

Its also important to remember that if you have clicked outside from the Profiler plugin, and did something else in QGIS, you click again the icon of the Profiler plugin to reactive it. Otherwise, it won't react to you choosing the Temp polyline, Selected polyline, or Selected layer.

After choosing the plugin again,  you can continue working with the selections.